# Notification doesn't show but doesn't throw any error altough [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just updated my ic_launcher in my android application (made in Android Studio, btw). I'm trying to create a test notification, and it used to work, but now it doesn't and I don't know why.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
builder
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle("TEST")
        .setContentText("Hello! This is a notification test!")
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

NotificationManager NoMa = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NoMa.notify(1, builder.build());
```

It doesn't even work if I remove the setLargeIcon line, which in my point of view makes no sense. I don't discard the possibility that there's something wrong with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `setSmallIcon()` if you want to show any notification.
So change your code to

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
builder
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //Any icon you want
        .setContentTitle("TEST")
        .setContentText("Hello! This is a notification test!")
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

NotificationManager NoMa = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NoMa.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: Omg. I didn't know that setSmallIcon was not optional, I supposed it should throwed me any error. Thank you very much guy!